# problem using base64 encoder and InputStreamReader

Tags: java, encoding, jdbc, base64, inputstreamreader

I have some CLOB columns in a database that I need to put Base64 encoded binary files in.
These files can be large, so I need to stream them, I can't read the whole thing in at once.

I'm using `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream` to do the encoding, and I'm running into a problem.  My code is essentially this

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(fis, true, -1, null);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(b64is));

preparedStatement.setCharacterStream(1, reader);
```

When I run the above code, I get one of these during the execution of the update
`java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes`, it is thrown deep in the InputStreamReader code.

Why would this not work?  It seems to me like the `reader` would attempt to read from the base 64 stream, which would read from the file stream, and everything should be happy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `Base64InputStream`.  You're calling it correctly.

You should report this to the Apache commons codec project.

Simple test case:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream;

class tmp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(fis, true, -1, null);

    while (true) {
      byte[] c = new byte[1024];
      int n = b64is.read(c);
      if (n < 0) break;
      if (n == 0) throw new IOException("returned 0!");
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)c[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `read(byte[])` call of `InputStream` is not allowed to return 0.  It does return 0 on any file which is a multiple of 3 bytes long.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is a bug in Base64InputStream. +1 for the testcase which confirms this.

Comment: Reported btw: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CODEC-101 That said, I'm still wondering about the coincidence that my test file was indeed a multiple of 3 bytes long :o)

Comment: Wow, thanks for confirming that, I must say I'm surprised that I found such a bug (however inadvertently).

Answer (score 4):

Interesting, I did some tests here and it indeed throws that exception when you read the `Base64InputStream` using an `InputStreamReader`, regardless the source of the stream, but it works flawlessly when you read it as binary stream. As Trashgod mentioned, Base64 encoding is framed. The `InputStreamReader` should in fact have invoked `flush()` on the `Base64InputStream` once more to see if it doesn't return any more data.

<strike>I don't see other ways to fix this than implementing your own `Base64InputStreamReader` or `Base64Reader`</strike>. *This is actually a bug, see Keith's answer.*

As a workaround you can also just store it in a BLOB instead of a CLOB in the DB and use `PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()` instead. It doesn't matter if it's stored as binary data or not. You don't want to have such large Base64 data to be indexable or searchable anyway.

---

**Update**: since that's not an option and having the Apache Commons Codec guys to fix the `Base64InputStream` bug which I repored as [CODEC-101](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CODEC-101) might take some time, you may consider to use another 3rd party Base64 API. I've found one [here](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) (public domain, so you can do whatever with it you want, even place in your own package), I've tested it here and it works fine.

```
InputStream base64 = new Base64.InputStream(input, Base64.ENCODE);
```

---

**Update 2**: the commons codec guy has [fixed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CODEC-101) it pretty soon.

```
Index: src/java/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.java
===================================================================
--- src/java/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.java (revision 950817)
+++ src/java/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64InputStream.java (working copy)
@@ -145,21 +145,41 @@
         } else if (len == 0) {
             return 0;
         } else {
-            if (!base64.hasData()) {
-                byte[] buf = new byte[doEncode ? 4096 : 8192];
-                int c = in.read(buf);
-                // A little optimization to avoid System.arraycopy()
-                // when possible.
-                if (c > 0 && b.length == len) {
-                    base64.setInitialBuffer(b, offset, len);
+            int readLen = 0;
+            /*
+             Rationale for while-loop on (readLen == 0):
+             -----
+             Base64.readResults() usually returns > 0 or EOF (-1).  In the
+             rare case where it returns 0, we just keep trying.
+
+             This is essentially an undocumented contract for InputStream
+             implementors that want their code to work properly with
+             java.io.InputStreamReader, since the latter hates it when
+             InputStream.read(byte[]) returns a zero.  Unfortunately our
+             readResults() call must return 0 if a large amount of the data
+             being decoded was non-base64, so this while-loop enables proper
+             interop with InputStreamReader for that scenario.
+             -----
+             This is a fix for CODEC-101
+            */
+            while (readLen == 0) {
+                if (!base64.hasData()) {
+                    byte[] buf = new byte[doEncode ? 4096 : 8192];
+                    int c = in.read(buf);
+                    // A little optimization to avoid System.arraycopy()
+                    // when possible.
+                    if (c > 0 && b.length == len) {
+                        base64.setInitialBuffer(b, offset, len);
+                    }
+                    if (doEncode) {
+                        base64.encode(buf, 0, c);
+                    } else {
+                        base64.decode(buf, 0, c);
+                    }
                 }
-                if (doEncode) {
-                    base64.encode(buf, 0, c);
-                } else {
-                    base64.decode(buf, 0, c);
-                }
+                readLen = base64.readResults(b, offset, len);
             }
-            return base64.readResults(b, offset, len);
+            return readLen;
         }
     }
```

I tried it here and it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use BLOB because sometimes the data in there will be text

Answer (score 0):

"For top efficiency, consider wrapping an [`InputStreamReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) within a [`BufferedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). For example:"

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(b64is));
```

Addendum: As [`Base64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is padded to a multiple of 4 characters, verify that the source isn't truncated. A `flush()` may be required.

Comment: Perhaps it is more efficient, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Any chance your stream is truncated? IIRC, `base64` is framed.

Comment: Question updated.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by "base64 is framed" ?  The stream comes directly from the file.

Comment: The encoded stream must be padded to "an integer multiple of 4 characters" in order to decode the last byte; this would be a problem if the stream were truncated. Reference cited above.

Comment: @trashgod - *"Reference cited above."*.  WHERE?

Comment: @Stephen C: "an integer multiple of 4 characters"—Base64 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64